# Get Distinct rows in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have SQL server query to fetch data from SQL Server to Python data frame as below. I need to  keep only unique rows based on two columns
**date** & **counter**

```
SELECT 
    CAST([A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] AS DATE) AS date,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D362_VALUE] AS counter,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D400_VALUE] AS D400,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D402_VALUE] AS D402,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D412_VALUE] AS D412,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D414_VALUE] AS D414,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D416_VALUE] AS D416,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D420_VALUE] AS D420,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D422_VALUE] AS D422,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D432_VALUE] AS D432
FROM 
    [aaaa2_tttt_a].[dbo].[tttt_a] 
WHERE
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] >= DATEADD(Hour, -1, GETDATE()) 
    AND [A2_TIRE_A_CO_L102_VALUE] = 1 
    AND [A2_TIRE_A_CO_L100_VALUE] = 1
```

```
| date       | counter | D400        | D402                         | D412        |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------------------------|-------------|
| 2022-04-23 | 2434    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2434    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2434    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2435    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2435    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2435    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2435    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
```

Requirement

```
| date       | counter | D400        | D402                         | D412        |
|------------|---------|-------------|------------------------------|-------------|
| 2022-04-23 | 2434    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
| 2022-04-23 | 2435    | 12848 14393 | 20808 8257 12339 13360 12601 | 16705 16948 |
```

I tried distinct method and other sources. How can I do it?

I tried to create new column by concatenating date and counter and applying distinct:

```
DISTINCT(CONCAT(CAST([A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] AS DATE),[A2_TIRE_A_CO_D362_VALUE]) AS unique_column)
```

but I think it is not correct way

Comment: I tried to create new column by concatenating date and counter and applying distinct: distinct(concat(CAST([A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] AS DATE),[A2_TIRE_A_CO_D362_VALUE]) as unique_column). but i think it is not correct way. unnecessary to create new column.

Comment: edited in question

Comment: I think in that question they ask for top row based on one column. My question is i want rows based on two columns

Comment: Same principle, you just adapt row_number to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use and `ORDER BY` window function of `ROW_NUMBER`.

`partition by` might need to put which column you want to represent `unique` row.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH 
    CAST([A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] AS DATE) as date,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D362_VALUE] as counter,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D400_VALUE] as D400,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D402_VALUE] as D402,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D412_VALUE] as D412,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D414_VALUE] as D414,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D416_VALUE] as D416,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D420_VALUE] as D420,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D422_VALUE] as D422,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D432_VALUE] as D432
FROM [aaaa2_tttt_a].[dbo].[tttt_a] 
where 
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] >= DATEADD(Hour,  -1,  GETDATE()) 
and 
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_L102_VALUE] =1 
and 
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_L100_VALUE] =1
order by row_number() over (partition by CAST([A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] AS DATE),[A2_TIRE_A_CO_D362_VALUE] order by date)
```

but I think you can use `DISTINCT` directly from your sample data and expect result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST([A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] AS DATE) as date,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D362_VALUE] as counter,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D400_VALUE] as D400,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D402_VALUE] as D402,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D412_VALUE] as D412,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D414_VALUE] as D414,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D416_VALUE] as D416,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D420_VALUE] as D420,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D422_VALUE] as D422,
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D432_VALUE] as D432
FROM [aaaa2_tttt_a].[dbo].[tttt_a] 
where 
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_D300_TIMESTAMP] >= DATEADD(Hour,  -1,  GETDATE()) 
and 
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_L102_VALUE] =1 
and 
    [A2_TIRE_A_CO_L100_VALUE] =1
```

Comment: 2nd one work. 1st one gives error. thanks!

Comment: This is such a common question you should be closing as a dup instead of answering.